# Component stays visible when using props in composition API

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a vue 3 app which display product information. The home component displays all available products. Each of them has a button which takes me to a component displaying information about said product called Single Box. It gets the product ID from the route params and then fetches additional information via graphql. It looks like this:

```js
<template>
<BoxDisplay :box="box"></BoxDisplay>
</template>

<script>
import { useQuery, useResult } from '@vue/apollo-composable';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import singleBoxQuery from '../graphql/singleBox.query.gql'
import BoxDisplay from '../components/BoxDisplay'

export default {
    components: {
        BoxDisplay
    },
    setup() {
        const route = useRoute();
        const boxId = route.params.id
        const {result } = useQuery(singleBoxQuery, {id: boxId})
        const box = useResult(result, null)
        return {
            boxId,
            box
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The BoxDisplay component is then used to show the infos of the current box. There is going to be more going on this page later so the BoxDisplay is needed. It looks like this:

```js
<template>
<div class="p-d-flex p-jc-center">
    <div v-if="box">
        <h1>{{box.Name}}</h1>
        <div v-html="myhtml"></div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <ProgressSpinner />
    </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: {
        box: {}
    },
    setup(props){
        const myhtml = "<h1>hello</h1>" + props.box.Name
        return {
            myhtml
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem is now, that as soon as I use props in setup() the component stay visible when I click back in my browser. It stays there until I refresh the page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use ref and computed
```

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#reactive-variables-with-ref

````
```

import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
```

const myhtml = computed(() => '<h1>hello</h1>' + props.box.Name)

or

const myhtml = ref('<h1>hello</h1>' + props.box.Name)
````